# Issue while setting mailer in pimcore(symfony) :- Invalid configuration for path "framework.mailer": "dsn" and "transports" cannot be used together

Tags: symfony, email, smtp, pimcore

Facing an issue with the mailer in pimcore 10.2 is made in symfony5.4.
**Invalid configuration for path "framework.mailer": "dsn" and "transports" cannot be used together.**
The setting I have done for the mail

```
# .env
MAILER_DSN=smtp://user:pass@smtp.example.com:port

# config/packages/mailer.yaml
framework:
    mailer:
        dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
```

I didn't set any other mail transport.

```
#### SYMFONY MAILER TRANSPORTS
#    mailer:
#        transports:
#            main: smtp://user:pass@smtp.example.com:port
#            pimcore_newsletter: smtp://user:pass@smtp.example.com:port
```

Error gone when I remove mailer.yaml file. But then mail is not sending.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in mailer.yaml.
It should be like

```
# config/packages/mailer.yaml
framework:
    mailer:
        transports:
            main: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
```

Comment: Very helpful, ran into exactly this after adding symfony flex to my pimcore app, and this solved it. Thanks! You should mark this as the accepted answer.